# Who Are The Highest Potential Players On Career Mode?

Tags: fifa-16

I'm wanting to make a squad with the highest potential players, so could you tell me the highest potential for each position for a 4-4-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know for each position but some high potential players are, Depay,Sterling, Iheanacho, Samper, Tielsman, Butland